# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 30, Size: 30 in onBindViewHolder() on Android

Tags: android

```
 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Log.d("position", "" + position);
    holder.tv_arsId.setText(arrivalInfoArrayList.get(position).getArsId());
    holder.tv_stNm.setText(arrivalInfoArrayList.get(position).getStNm());
 }
```

arrivalInfoArrayList size is 30, and position log printed 0 - 30.

I know this error occurred because index starts with 0 and size starts with 1.

I tried these.

1)

```
if (position > 0) {
    holder.tv_arsId.setText(arrivalInfoArrayList.get(position - 1).getArsId());
    holder.tv_stNm.setText(arrivalInfoArrayList.get(position - 1).getStNm());
}
```

2)

```
for ( int i = 0; i < arrivalInfoArrayList.size(); i++) {
    holder.tv_arsId.setText(arrivalInfoArrayList.get(position).getArsId());
    holder.tv_stNm.setText(arrivalInfoArrayList.get(position).getStNm());
}
```

But it didn't work. position log still printed 0 - 30 and the error occurred.

I searched posts but I don't know how to fix it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have correct implementation of `getItemCount`?

Comment: post your getItemCount() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your adapter you have to use:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrivalInfoArrayList.size();
}
```